# Trying to replace newline character with comma in MS word table from email, search on ^p didn't work

Tags: microsoft-word

I'm trying to replace newline character, the symbol `↵`, with comma in an MS Word table that was copied from email. Searching on `^p` didn't work, nor did `^l`, either.

Comment: Try to search for `^13`.

Comment: I believe word does regex'es, at least for some settings; when set up for that, \r = CR, \n = LF, which frequently are used (together) for line change in files under Windows.

Comment: Also try `^10`.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to search and replace a character [or string, since end-of-line convention can be *two* characters, CHR(13)CHR(10), CR-LF, for example] is to select the text (the symbol ↵) and *then* open the search/replace dialog -- the selected text should appear as the search term.

However, sometimes it's easier to copy the text into a text editor, such as Kate, Notepad++ or Notepad, and perform the search/replace there, since *each* 8-bit character code can be displayed as ANSI (ASCII) character. The image shows that the symbol **↵** in the question is actually **three** 8-bit codes, **â†µ**.

[image: Characters shown in Notepad++]